# ReactTooltip is only updated when leaving tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, mapbox-gl-js

I am using React with MapGL and a DeckGLOverlay. I want to show tooltips on the DeckGLOverlay:

```
setTooltip(features) { 
  document.getElementById("body").dataset.tip = features.object.centroid
}

render() {
    const {viewport, data} = this.state;

    return (
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange.bind(this)}        
        onLoad={this.showLayer.bind(this)}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={mapboxgl.accessToken}
      >
        <ReactTooltip />
        <DeckGLOverlay viewport={viewport} data={data || []} onHover={this.setTooltip} />
      </MapGL>
    );
}
```

The tooltips are shown, but the content is only update when I either leave the tab and come back to it or I move the mouse cursor outside the body area and then move it back to the DeckGLOverlay.

How can I force ReactTooltip to refresh its content while I am hovering over different areas of DeckGLOverlay?

Comment: where `features` came from?

Comment: `DeckGLOverlay` adds it as a parameter when `setTooltip` is called. `features` is a dict containing information like the center of the polygone that is hovered.

Comment: I checked via `console.log` if `features` contains what it should and it does. So the problem is really just that the tooltip is only refreshed when I move the mouse outside the viewport and than in again.

Comment: maybe changing `onHover` with `onMouseOver` fix it?

Comment: Tried it, then nothing happens